# How to make an already running PL SQL package run faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

There is a PL SQL package which has been called by a job. I have run the job and I was monitoring the progress by running a query on the log table which gets populated for each record. There are 20k records to be processed. The code ran reasonably fast for first 8-10k records. After that , the speed slowed down considerably. The code is still running and it is very slow now. I checked all the active sessions and there are no issues. Can a booster be applied without killing the job?

Comment: Only half jokingly (and half seriously): Buy a faster CPU, and more memory, etc. I heard from friends who are software engineers at Facebook that this is often the way they make things faster; newer, more powerful hardware is much cheaper than the cost of changing code that is already working (especially when you consider the cost of thorough testing of all changes, documenting the changes, etc.)

Comment: Specifically to your question: The "booster" may be killing other processes that hog either the CPU or memory resources (or both), so they are freed up for your job. Will this be a valid solution for you? Only you know.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the code, the database, and the environment they're running in there's really no way to answer your question.

Comment: Show us the PL/SQL package and where it is getting slow.

Comment: Without knowing what work this is doing it's impossible to say. 20k records should be updated VERY quickly if that's all it doing. If there are multiple operations for each of those 20k that is a totally different prospect. Seeing the code would help as a starter and an indication of the environment set-up - parallel, RAC, etc.

Comment: set fast=true in the init.ora ?

Answer (score -2):

Try inserting commit for every 5 k of records processed